# Listing directories and understanding ls

Tags: shell, directory, ls, wildcards

On `ls` man page, I saw this

```
 -d, --directory

    list directory entries instead of contents, and do not 
    dereference symbolic links
```

on my current folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Jul 13 11:52 folderd
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Jul 13 11:52 folderc
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Jul 13 11:52 folderb
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Jul 13 11:52 foldera
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall    0 Jul 13 11:52 filed
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall    0 Jul 13 11:52 filec
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall    0 Jul 13 11:52 fileb
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall    0 Jul 13 11:52 filea
```

q1) Doing a `ls -ld` show me a `.` - why?

```
[oracle@centos1 script]$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 6 oracle oinstall 4096 Jul 13 11:52 .
```

doing a `ls -l *`, give me everything including the files in the folder:

```
[oracle@centos1 script]$ ls -l *
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall    0 Jul 13 11:52 filea
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall    0 Jul 13 11:52 fileb
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall    0 Jul 13 11:52 filec
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall    0 Jul 13 11:52 filed

foldera:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall 0 Jul 13 11:57 fileafolda
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall 0 Jul 13 11:55 fileainfolda

folderb:
total 0

folderc:
total 0

folderd:
total 0
```

Doing a `ls -ld */` and it shows me the right result, only folders.

```
[oracle@centos1 script]$ ls -ld */
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Jul 13 11:57 foldera/
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Jul 13 11:52 folderb/
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Jul 13 11:52 folderc/
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Jul 13 11:52 folderd/
```

q3) what does `ls` actually take in as a parameter?  `*` here means everything including folder.  and `*/` means folder only, and `-d` here removes folder content.

If that's the case, why doesn't `ls -ld` show any result at all. only a `.` at q1?

In short, does it means that:

1. `ls -l` = `ls -l .` = list all contents in current directory
2. `ls -l *` = list all contents in current directory + the contents in the sub -directories
3. `ls -ld` = `ls -ld .` = list the current directory but not its content (hence the .)
4. `ls -l */` = list all sub-directories + its content in this current directory
5. `ls -ld */` = list all sub-directories but not its content in this current directory

q1) But I do not understand the following below

Assuming I am inside `/script`.

`ls -l *` → list all contents inside the current directory, including it subdirectories's content.

`ls -ld *` →  list all contents inside the current directory, excluding subdirectories's content.

Here the `-d` is taking effect on the subdirectories inside the current directory.

But `ls -ld .` → the "-d"  is not meant to be use for the subdirectories, but actually for the current directory itself.

I don't understand why is the `-d` affecting the current directory and not its contents.

Comment: I do not understand your new question "q1)" after the edit. Are you mixing up `-d` with `-r`? `-r` will recursively descend and show the contents of the contents of directories, and so on. But without `-r` `ls` only lists the directories it has been asked to list and stops there. `-d` does not change that.

Comment: @Celada thanks for the reply. nope , it is nothing to do with -r, let me rephrase my question again.

Comment: "But ls -ld . -> the "-d" is not meant to be use for the subdirectories, but actually for the current directory itself." — well, yes, that's what you asked for by asking `ls` to list `.` (the current directory). So it shows the current directory but not its contents, which is the point of `-d`.

Comment: "I don't understand why is the "-d" refering/affecting the current directory and not its contents." — it affects its contents when what's what you ask `ls` to list.

Comment: In conclusion, I'm afraid I must still be missing something in your explanation.

Comment: ls -l * is also listing everything in the current directory
ls -l . is listing everything in the current directory, just without the subdirectories 'content

but ls -ld * is affecting the subdirectories, not the current directory

Comment: Yes, this is all expected and correct, and exactly what you asked `ls` to do. For example, for the last: `ls -ld*` yes of course it is affecting subdirectories and not the current directory, because subdirectories (and other files) are exactly what you supplied to `ls` to list.

Answer (score 4):

> q1) Doing a ls -ld show me a . - why ?

When you give no arguments to `ls`, the default is to run the command on the current directory, also known as `.`. Normally that means listing the contents of the directory, but you have used the `-d` option which requests listing the directory *itself*, not its contents. So you get the information for `.`, the current directory.

> doing a ls -ld *, give me everything including the files in the folder

No, it doesn't. `ls -ld *` will list each file in the current directory matching `*` (which is all of them excet hidden ones) but *not* the contents of those that are directories, again because you used `-d`. Note that your example output does something different because it does *not* use `-d`.

> doing a ls -ld */ and it shows me the right result, only folders.

Only directories match the pattern `*/`, because regular files cannot have pathnames ending in `/`.

> q3) what does "ls" actually take in as a parameter ? * here means everything including folder. and */ means folder only, and -d here remove folder content.

All basically correct. To expand: `*` matches everything except hidden files, `*/` is the same but only matches directories, and you have the meaning of the `-d` option just right.

> if that's the case, why doesn't ls -ld show any result at all. only a . at q1

It does show a result: it shows the current directory, which is known as `.`!

Comment: thanks. I have changed my original post and question under EDIT 1, please take a look

Comment: `ls */` also lists files (and also subdirectories) - which contradicts what you wrote (6 years ago... ;) Why?